# How to organise this 2-3 layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout

Here is the picture what I want to do

[image]

I dont really care about elements in **< >** (I know how to declare them), I just want to organise red and blue labels to do not collide themselves (like blue is above red, so I can't display red one ofc). I used to work with C# UI desinger, or CPP, so this is quite new for me, and I am just a beginner :(

My current code of UI:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="431dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="SEARCH BOX" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I got some rendering problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use layout weights to achieve this.

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="SEARCH BOX" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Ummm, can't see any code, or whatever reffers to "this", but I will google a little bit around layout weights :)

Comment: Some how stackoverflow did not display the code. I have been writing this post on my mobile phone using the stackoverflow app. It should now be fixed.